# How to include class name when calling to_json in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, serialization

I'm trying to implement autocomplete that lets user to pick from list of 2 different kind of models.

This is how my controller looks:

```
def ac
  arr = []
  arr << Foo.all
  arr << Bar.all
  render json: arr.to_json
end
```

Which renders:

```
[[{"id":1, "name":"foo name"}], [{"id":1, "name":"bar name"}]]
```

How to include class name and get something like this:

```
[
 [{"id":1, "name":"foo name", "class_name":"Foo"}],
 [{"id":1, "name":"bar name", "class_name":"Bar"}]
]
```

?

Comment: I think you forgot curly braces around attributes. Besides that, do you have `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json` set to `false`? If it's `true` then AR includes class name (underscored and demodulized, though) as a root element of json hash.

Comment: @KL-7 didn't pay too much attention on json validness. have read about `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json` but I think that it's quite dirty approach because it changes settings application wide.

Comment: It's better to have you examples valid in the question, as they don't make sense right now and that makes it harder to understand what you mean. Regarding `include_root_in_json` I thought it's set to `true` by default. Did you change it yourself?

Comment: @KL-7 using 3.2.1 rails. I think they changed default settings for `include_root_in_json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind doing a bit of extra work you can do smth like that with `:methods` option of `as_json` method (and `to_json` as well):

```
class Foo
  def class_name
    self.class.name
  end
end

arr = Foo.all.map { |foo| foo.as_json(:methods => [:class_name]) }
puts arr.to_json
#=> [{ "id": 1, "name": "foo name", "class_name": "Foo" }]
```

If you have `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json` set to `true` (that is default afaik) then you'll get hashes like

```
{ "foo": { "id": 1, "name": "foo name" } }
```

If you want it to be exactly the class name you can pass `:root` option:

```
foo = Foo.last
puts foo.to_json(:root => foo.class.name)
#=> { "Foo": { "id": 1, "name": "foo name" } }
```

Note that both these solutions do not allow you simply to call `to_json` on an array of records. To overcome that and make `class_name` included by default you can override [`serializable_hash`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serialization/serializable_hash) method in your model like that:

```
def serializable_hash(*)
  super.merge('class_name' => self.class.name)
end
```

If you wrap it into a module you can include it in any model you want and get `class_name` included into the result of `as_json` or `to_json` without passing any extra options to these methods. You can modify the implementation a bit to respect `:except` option if you want to exclude `class_name` in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

ended up adding 1 additional step:

```
arr << Foo.all
arr << Bar.all
arr.flatten!
arr=arr.collect{|itm| {"id":"#{itm.class.to_s}:#{itm.id}", "value":itm.name}}
```

then I just spit it out:

```
render json: arr.to_json()
```

as a result I get:

```
[{"id":"Foo:1", "value":"Foo #1"},{"id":"Bar:1", "value":"Bar #1"}]
```